# Last Histogram Bar Missing - PgfPlots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to plot a logarithmic histogram with bins based on orders of magnitude.

I've got this source:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogxaxis}[xlabel=Number of Active Satellites, ylabel=Frequency]
\addplot[color=red, ybar interval]
plot coordinates {(5.5,856) (55,110) (550,14) (5500,122)};
\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Number of active satellites controlled by operator}
\label{fig:satellitesbyoperatorhisto}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Which produces this output:

[image: PgfPlot]

You can see that the last bar (1000 <= x < 10000) seems to be missing.

Why?

Comment: Four points give three intervals. There are three bars. -nothing is missing.

Comment: Sorry what? Am I totally misunderstanding how pgfplots bar charts work... Do you not just define the centre-point of the bar? That would explain why everything looks a bit squiff...

Comment: I am not at a computer right now, so I can not test. -also your code can not compile in its current state. Please add everything needed to compile. Try to remove the option `ybar interval` and add `ybar`.

Comment: I need `ybar interval` because it's a histogram. If I just use `ybar` I get the 4 bars but with unwanted gaps between them. I think I may have misunderstood how `ybar interval` works

Comment: In the package documentation is stated: *There is one conceptional difference when working with intervals: an interval is defined by two coordinates.
Since ybar has one value for each interval, the ith bar is defined by
1. the y value of the ith coordinates,
2. the x value of the ith coordinate as left interval boundary,
3. the x value of the (i + 1)th coordinate as right interval boundary.
Consequently, there is one coordinate too much: the last coordinate will only be used to determine the
interval width; its y value doesn’t influence the bar appearance.*.

Comment: Ahh, I'd missed that... Thanks @Zarko, that should probably be an answer rather than a comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let extend me my comment to an answer.

In the package documentation, page 87, is about *ybar interval* stated:

> There is one conceptional difference when working with intervals: an
> interval is defined by two coordinates. Since ybar has one value for
> each interval, the ith bar is defined by
>
> 1. the y value of the ith coordinates,
> 2. the x value of the ith coordinate as left interval boundary,
> 3. the x value of the (i + 1)th coordinate as right interval boundary.
>
> Consequently, there is one coordinate too much: the last coordinate will only be used to determine the interval width; its y value doesn’t
> influence the bar appearance.

Regarding this, your image, that in case should have four interval bars need additional coordinate for determining  last interval. In it is important *x*-coordinate, , *y* can be doomy:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogxaxis}[xlabel=Number of Active Satellites, ylabel=Frequency]
\addplot[color=red, ybar interval]
plot coordinates {(5.5,856) (55,110) (550,14) (5500,122) 
                   (55000,0)};  % <--- dummy y vale, just determine last interwal width
\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Number of active satellites controlled by operator}
\label{fig:satellitesbyoperatorhisto}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you!